# Add a column to existing class of sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, sqlalchemy-migrate

I have a parent class that generates a unique id and a child class having a username.

```py
class Ids(object): 
    id = Column(Integer, Sequence('res_id_seq'), primary_key=True) 


class Names(Ids, base): 
    username = Column(String(50))

# I have created an sqlite db and persisting using sqlalchemy

engine = create_engine('sqlite:///emp.db', echo=True)
base.metadata.create_all(engine)
```

I want to add a column to Names (lastname). How can i do that with sqlalchemy-migrate?
Any examples would be helpful?

Answer (score 0):

See this section of the SQLAlchemy documentation from [here](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/metadata.html#altering-schemas-through-migrations)

> While SQLAlchemy directly supports emitting CREATE and DROP statements for schema constructs, the ability to alter those constructs, usually via the ALTER statement as well as other database-specific constructs, is outside of the scope of SQLAlchemy itself.
> **The SQLAlchemy project offers the [Alembic](http://alembic.readthedocs.org/) migration tool for this purpose.**

You can follow the explanation here on how you can add a column of your choice to the class `Names` - [Alembic-Create a Migration Script](https://alembic.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/tutorial.html#create-a-migration-script)

Answer (score 0):

According to [sqlalchemy-migrate documentation](https://sqlalchemy-migrate.readthedocs.io/en/latest/changeset.html#column) use can use `create` and `drop` methods on columns in your migrations. Your migrate script may loop like this:

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, MetaData, String, Table

metadata = MetaData()

# Note that here you use Table instance
# not the class derived from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative.declarative_base
names = Table(
    'names',
    metadata,
    # You need to specify only primary key column
    # if you just adding a new column in this script
    Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True),
)

lastname = Column('lastname', String(50))


def upgrade(migrate_engine):
    metadata.bind = migrate_engine
    lastname.create(names)


def downgrade(migrate_engine):
    metadata.bind = migrate_engine
    names.append_column(lastname)
    names.c.lastname.drop()
```

[More](https://sqlalchemy-migrate.readthedocs.io/en/latest/versioning.html) on creating migration scripts.